# Folland 4.5 Proposition - Every second countable space is separable

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I have a question regarding the following theorem from Folland's Real Analysis. I understand that the complement of the closure is an open set. Why does the complement of the closure of $\{x_U:U\in \mathcal{E}\}$ not include any $U\in \mathcal{E}$?

> **4.5 Proposition.** Every second countable space is separable
>
> If $X$ is secound countable, let $\mathcal{E}$ be a countable base for
> the topology and for each $U\in \mathcal{E}$, picck a point $x_U \in
>  U$. Then the complement of the closure of $\{x_U:U\in \mathcal{E}\}$
> is an open set that does not include any $U \in \mathcal{E}$; hence it
> is empty and $\{x_U: U\in \mathcal{E}\}$ is dense.

Comment: For any $U \in \mathcal{E}$, the complement of the closure doesn't contain $x_U$, so it can't contain all of $U$: $U$ is not a subset of the complement of the closure.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Ah so it's an open set which doesn't contain any of the open sets therefore it must be empty?

Comment: Or look at it this way, the complement is open, so if it is non empty it must contain at least one of the $U$s  and hence the $x_U$ which is an immediate contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

A set is dense iff it intersects every non-empty open set.

The set $D:=\{x_U\mid U \in \mathcal{U}\}$ obeys that property: let $O$ be open and non-empty. So $x \in O$ exists. By the property of a base we have some $U_0 \in \mathcal{U}$ so that $x \in U_0 \subseteq O$. But then $x_{U_0} \in D \cap O$ and we're done.

I don't see why the book chose a proof from contradiction. It's correct but confusing: $O:=X\setminus \overline{D}$ is open (by definition). As $x_U \in D$ we know $x_U \notin O$ so $U \nsubseteq O$ is witnessed by $x_U$. As a non-empty $O$ must be a non-trivial union of subsets from $\mathcal{U}$, it must be empty.
Why use a double negative if a direct proof is as easy as the first paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

If $V:=X\setminus\overline{\{x_U:U\in\mathcal{E}\}}$ contained a set $U_0\in\mathcal{E}$, then the point $x_{U_0}\in U_0$ would also be an element of $V$. Obviously $x_{u_0}\in\{x_u:U\in\mathcal{E}\}\subset\overline{\{x_U:U\in\mathcal{E}\}}$;  however, $x_{U_0}\in V$ implies that $x_{U_0}\notin\overline{\{x_U:U\in\mathcal{E}\}}$ which is absurd. Consequently, no set $U$ in $\mathcal{E}$ is contained in $V$ and so, $V=\emptyset$.